# Search PHPMYADMIN Database for similar entrys

Tags: sql, database, search, phpmyadmin

So i have database with a table called users..  and in that table there is a column named IP and i want to find users with the same IP and ban them.. So how can a search the datebase for IP's are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leverage the group by query. An old blog I wrote is [Understanding group bys](http://www.endyourif.com/understanding-group-bys/)

But basically this should work:

```
select distinct ip, count(id) from users group by IP having count(id) > 1
```

This will return all ip addresses with a count of > 1

Answer (score 0):

Run a SQL statement and substitute for the IP address you want to search for:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE IP = '172.0.0.1'
```

Comment: i don't want to search for a certain IP i want to search for IP's that are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can start by:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM tablename
GROUP BY IP
```

Then you just join those results back onto the table to get information about the duplicates

So modify the first statement with:
   SELECT count(id) as number, IP FROM tablename

Then

```
   SELECT a.id, a.name FROM tablename a
   JOIN (
        SELECT count(id) as number, IP FROM tablename
    ) b ON a.IP = b.IP
    WHERE number > 1
```

This should give you all the duplicate IP addresses in the Database. You may have to figure out a way to decide on which account to keep and which to remove, but this should give you a start.

Comment: my table name is users and column name is IP

Comment: i get #1054 - Unknown column 'a.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Please list all of the columns in that table and I will give you the statement. A.name is just a column in the table aliased as 'a'(I was guessing that's what the name was). You could put any column name from the table Users there (preceded by "a.") and it will work.